# Why do you need to sometimes list a library twice for C link and is it avoidable?

Tags: c, linker, ld

I am compiling a program and was getting an "undefined reference" to a constant variable defined in a C file in lib1 which is used in lib2. I get the error if I compile as:

```
clang myfile.c -L. -L../lib2dir -llib1 -llib2
```

I remembered from my Unix days that sometime you have to add a library again. So I did:

```
clang myfile.c -L. -L../lib2dir -llib1 -llib2 -llib1
```

and it linked. Why is this still necessary or am I doing something wrong and it shouldn't be necssary?

Comment: for grins did you try lib2 first then lib1? rather than one two one or one two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The libraries are linked in the order in which they are placed on the command line. When a library is linked, only the missing symbols are resolved from it. Since the symbol that you mention is in `lib2`, it will not be resolved from `lib1`, because the linker does not know yet that it will be needed later. So, put `-llib2` in front of `-llib1`.

Comment: Thanks, it  does work if I reverse the order of them. I still think the linker should be smart enough to go back and look for it or keep a list of everything that was in lib1 for when it  processes lib2.

Comment: Well... It should. But it isn't.